# Cannot connect to wifi after resetting network settings

Tags: wifi, ios

I am currently running 8.1.2 on an iphone 6 plus. I have recently noticed that the internet became practically unusuable so i decided to reset my network settings. I tried signing back in to the same wifi I used on my other devices and it gave me the "incorrect password" error. So at first i thought of trying to forget and reconnect to the network on my iphone 5s(also running 8.1.2) to make sure i wasn't typing the weong password, but it worked. Next i tried to go into the router settings and copy the password onto my 6 plus but still could not connect. I've never gotten this problem before.

EDIT:
I will try and update to ios 9, if it still does not work. I'm going to apple to exchange and get back on how it goes

Update:
I decided to hard reset and restore my phone and the wifi started working again. The problem has been solved, i do not know how but i would appreciate anyone's answer might there be any future problems

Comment: A lot of the updates to iOS 8 were to fix connectivity issues

Comment: someone help i cant connect after resetting network settings because it shows wifi but i cant turn it on please im panicking

Answer (score 1):

I had that issue on an iphone 5 a bunch of times. All the other apple devices worked just fine. Very frustrating. There's a thread on one of the support forums with hundreds of replies from folks with similar issues but no real solutions. We replaced the router as well but that did not fix it. After the phone was replaced with same model it went away so I think it may have been a hardware issue. When I had the issue, a workaround I found was to use 5GHz only as the 2.4Ghz gave the issues but the 5GHz did not. HTH

Comment: My router is already set to 5GHz but still seems to have issues. I tried to reset my router but still would not work.

Comment: Have you tried changing the channel it is on? Also try 2.4GHz channels to see if they give same result. Being a 6 you can also do a chat with Apple support online for no money. They will have you send diagnostics and then have you do a bunch of different things. They can be quite helpful. OTOH since you are not on the latest version of iOS they may not be as helpful. You can always try.